# Android get url with onclick

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

Hello I am trying to get the value of a url with onclick but it is not working for me.  I am usign the following code.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String valueOfURL = null;
WebView webView;
Intent browserIntent;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}

public String handleLinkClicked(String value) {
    if (value.startsWith("http"))  

    valueOfURL = value;
    return valueOfURL;

}
public View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
    handleLinkClicked(valueOfURL);
    webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=valueOfURL");
    }};
}
```

The first page will load fine but when i click on a pdf on that page it wont load.  Basically what I am trying to do is get the value of the URL and pass it to a variable that is then used to be read via google docs.  It is a pdf file and its URL looks like this 
    http://wwww.example.com/c/document_library/get_file?

Can anyone see where I am going wrong and maybe point me in the right direction.

Thanking You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set your `onClickListener()` `myhandler` to any `View`. Your code (`browserIntent`) starts an implicit `intent` that will automatically start a Web browser (new `Activity` not linked to your application) to handle your URL. If you need to control the browsing from your App, you should implement a `WebView` inside your Layout and set your `onClickListener` to it instead of using implicit intents. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ires) on how Android handles implicit intents

Comment: Check my updated answer. You should have a WebView inside your Layout and set its layout programmatically. Using "android.intent.action.VIEW" will start an implicit intent that is left for Android system to decide how to open. It will not load it in the WebView inside your layout.